# Login authentication using MVP pattern

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, mvp

How can I improve my login script and is there a cleaner way to get the same result? I had this project and redesigned it using MVP patten . Working with this patten is a new challenge for me. It's hard to tell if I've done the best work possible.

My project is composed of Models, Views, Presenter, Repository

In my `program.cs` I initialized my `loginView`:

```
ILoginView view = new LoginFrom();
new LoginPresentor(view, sqlConnectionString);
Application.Run((Form)view);
```

The login Form Shows up and I enter Username and Password and click on Singin would run this:

Presentor/`LoginPresentor.cs`

```
private void Login(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        bool emptyUser = _loginView.UserName == "";
        bool emptyPassword = _loginView.Password == "";

        if(emptyUser!= true && emptyPassword != true)
        {
            IUsersRepository _userRepository = new UserRepository(_sqlConnectionString);
            _isLoggedIn = _userRepository.GetByUserAndPassword(_loginView.UserName, _loginView.Password);
            if(_isLoggedIn)
            {
                _loginView.Hide();
                IMainView view = new DashboardForm();
                new MainPresentor(view, _sqlConnectionString);
            }
        }
        
    }
```

what I'm doing here is create the function to check for the user and password in the database in the `UserView` where I can enter and delete etc.. and I add new Repository to the UserView to get the data and check if a get any data data return true else return false and use it in the Login Form to show the next View

**This is the Rest of the code**

Models/ `IUserRepository.cs` (interface)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Inventory.Model
{
    public interface IUsersRepository
    {
        void Add(UserModel userModel);
        void Update(UserModel userModel);
        void Delete(int id);
        IEnumerable<UserModel> GetAll(); // Populate all Data
        IEnumerable<UserModel> GetByvalue(string value); // For Search
        bool GetByUserAndPassword(string name, string password); // Get Data By username and password
    }
}
```

_Repository/`UserRepository.cs`

```
public bool GetByUserAndPassword(string name, string password)
{
    var userList = new List<UserModel>();
    bool isLogin;
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = @"Select * FROM Users where UserName = @name And UserPassword = @password";
            command.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = name;
            command.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = password;
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var userModel = new UserModel();
                    userModel.Id = (int)reader[0];
                    userModel.Name = reader[1].ToString();
                    userModel.Password = reader[2].ToString();
                    userModel.Role = reader[3].ToString();
                    userList.Add(userModel);                        
                }
            if (userList.Count > 0)
                isLogin = true;                       
            isLogin = false;
        }
    return isLogin;
}
```

*Note I still did not add Error message to Failed Login

Answer (score 4):

Some quick remarks:

- Who taught you to do this: `bool emptyUser = _loginView.UserName == "";`? Why not use what everyone uses: `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`?
- You say `IUserRepository.cs` is in the folder `Models`, despite it not being a model but a repository. But then its namespace is `Inventory.Model`, so that means its namespace doesn't correspond with its location (Model" vs "Models"). This is bad.
- Don't use ADO.NET. Use a lightweight ORM like Dapper, or a full ORM like Entity Framework.
- Don't store a password in plain text in your database. There are plenty of technologies available to securely manage users; at the very least you'll need to encrypt the password. Look into subjects like authentication and authorization.

Comment: Thank you For these helpful notes, I Edit the way to check for empty values and for the 'Inventory.Model' I've changed the folder name seems that some of the namespace use the old Name I update it as well now all of them refer to Models